# Return dictionary from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, return

I've been searching stackoverflow for a few hours now without finding a solution to my problem. I have a function where I want the output to be a dictionary, but I can only get it to print the first key + value. The "yield" statement won't work for some reason, so I'm wondering if there is another way to do it.

This is my code:

```
def myfunc(somedict):
    x = list(somedict.values())      
    for i in x:
        data = dict_from_otherfunc(i)
        mylist = [float(max(data.values()))]
        mydict = dict(zip([i], mylist))
        return mydict
```

This returns a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'abc': 1}
```

When I put print instead of return I get the desired output. How can i make this code return a dictionary with all values instead of only one?

Edit:
Tried returning outside of for-loop, this returns only the *last* value of my dictionary.

Comment: You are `return`ing within the `for` loop so the function exits after storing the first value in the dictionary.

Comment: SO is not a place where you come to learn how to use  'for' loop.

Find a good programming resource and learn and practice a bit of coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** If I understand correctly, the problem lies in the `for` loop itself. You set the value of mydict on every iteration, so of course it only returns one of them.

Now, I'm not fully certain if I understand what you're trying to do, but if I do, I'd recommend trying something like this:

```
def myfunc(somedict):
    x = list(somedict.values())
    mylist = [float(max(dict_from_otherfunc(i).values()) for i in x] # You can split this into two lines to make it more readable, I suppose
    mydict = dict(zip(x, mylist)
    return mydict
```

This would also benefit from renaming your variables a bit and such, but I'm assuming this is just an example.

Comment: I tried, when I do that I only get the last item of the dictionary...

Comment: Ah, of course! My bad. Hold on, I'll figure it out in a minute.

Comment: Check the new answer. It should work now - what it does is zip together a value of the first dictionary with the highest value of the dictionary it returns when used as an argument in another function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked!

Comment: @LeszekKicior You are kind enough to teach him how to use for loop.
Where will it stop?